# Apache Airflow 2 does not execute the task after upgrading from 1.1

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, airflow

I upgraded to Airflow 2.0 today (docker) and since then, I am not able to execute any tasks (they fail successfully, but get stuck at the green with the below error).

Edit: I am editing this to highlight the difference between the vanilla docker-compose file, and the changes I specifically made.

```
airflow_worker       | 
airflow_worker       | 
airflow_worker       | airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: celery subcommand works only with CeleryExecutor, your current executor: SequentialExecutor, see help above.
airflow_worker       | usage: airflow [-h] GROUP_OR_COMMAND ...
airflow_worker       | shows all the options here
airflow_worker       |   -h, --help         show this help message and exit
airflow_worker exited with code 2
```

I used the standard docker-compose and made minor changes to suit my need. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.1}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2:**//xxx:xxx@db/xxx**
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: **db+postgresql://xxx:xxx@db/xxx**
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: '**xxx**'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: '**false**'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: airflow
    _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: airflow
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    **- ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin**
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-1000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    db:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  db:
    image: **postgres:latest**
    **env_file:
      - database.env**
    **volumes:
      - ./db/:/var/lib/postgresql/data**
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "airflow", "-U", "airflow" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    container_name: redis_queue
    image: redis:6.2.6-bullseye
    command: redis-server --requirepass redispass
    **env_file:
      - redis.env**
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow_web
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow_scheduler
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: flower_web
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow_worker
    command: **celery** worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  **airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully**
  
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: always
    e**nv_file:
      - pg_admin.env**
    ports:
    - "8060:80"
    links:
    - "db:pgsql-server"

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .**/airflow**:/sources

volumes:
  db:
  pgadmin-data:
  dags:
  logs:
  plugins:
```

The error keeps showing every few minutes, or whenever airflow attempts executing my task.

Comment: can you point out what changes you made in docker-compose?

Comment: @khari-sing: done. Highlighted with double asterisks

Comment: I use the base docker-compose file from here, but some are changed. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: it works (after 24 hours of trying), but I have no idea why it worked. I will try to dig up an answer and post it here

Comment: since the issue is solved for you without making any additional changes in the docker-compose; my guess would be scheduler somehow read the `AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR` as SequentialExecutor (default) and not the CeleryExecutor as you configured. You could try doing a restart just for the scheduler container or doing a docker-compose down followed by docker-compose up

Comment: Thanks, I will do some experiments this weekend to find out what happened. I even clean the installed docker (I use a Linux machine) resulting in the same error. When it worked, it just worked after failing four times prior to that. So far it hasn't failed during multiple restarts (trying to see whether it fails again). However, I need to find why it works, and so I am gonna dig further.

Comment: You can do a `docker inspect` on your container to find out what env variables were passed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when migrating to Airflow 2.2.3:

> airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: `airflow worker`
> command, has been removed, please use `airflow celery worker`, see
> help above.

Changing the entrypoint/command to the following fixed the issue:

```
airflow celery worker
```